# Why Does My Regex Ignore Plus or Minus Signs?

Tags: regex, vb.net, .net-3.5

No matter what I try, it never matches the sign. I even tried using the string as the pattern. This function should be able to take a string like `1 day -36mins + 2s -1s` and parse it into a `TimeSpan` object. Any pointers?

```
Public Function ParseTimeDelta(ByVal TimeDelta As String) As TimeSpan
    Dim DayPattern As String = "\b([+-]?\w*\d+)\s*d(?:ay[s]?)?\b"
    Dim HourPattern As String = "\b([+-]?\w*\d+)\s*h(?:(?:ou)?r[s]?)?\b"
    Dim MinutePattern As String = "\b([+-]?\w*\d+)\s*m(?:in(?:ute)?[s]?)?\b"
    Dim SecondPattern As String = "\b([+-]?\w*\d+)\s*s(?:ec(?:ond)?[s]?)?\b"
    Dim Days As Integer = 0
    Dim Hours As Integer = 0
    Dim Minutes As Integer = 0
    Dim Seconds As Integer = 0
    Dim Regex As Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(DayPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Days += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(HourPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Hours += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(MinutePattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Minutes += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(SecondPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Seconds += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Return New TimeSpan(Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
End Function
```

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: @KendallFrey, Well, to make it simple, I'll give you some valid matches for seconds: `1s`, `1 sec`, `-23 seconds`, `1secs`, `- 10 second`.

Comment: You should include those in the question, as well as narrow down the problem a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't matching because there was no word boundary before the signs. Fixed.

```
Public Function ParseTimeDelta(ByVal TimeDelta As String) As TimeSpan
    Dim DayPattern As String = "((?:[+-]|\b)\w*\d+)\s*d(?:ay[s]?)?\b"
    Dim HourPattern As String = "((?:[+-]|\b)\w*\d+)\s*h(?:(?:ou)?r[s]?)?\b"
    Dim MinutePattern As String = "((?:[+-]|\b)\w*\d+)\s*m(?:in(?:ute)?[s]?)?\b"
    Dim SecondPattern As String = "((?:[+-]|\b)\w*\d+)\s*s(?:ec(?:ond)?[s]?)?\b"
    Dim Days As Integer = 0
    Dim Hours As Integer = 0
    Dim Minutes As Integer = 0
    Dim Seconds As Integer = 0
    Dim Regex As Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(DayPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Days += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(HourPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Hours += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(MinutePattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Minutes += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(SecondPattern, Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    For Each Match As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(TimeDelta)
        Seconds += CInt(Match.Groups(1).Value)
    Next

    Return New TimeSpan(Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
End Function
```